# docker-compose cannot recognize sudoers container file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have PHP Dockerfile:

```
...
USER root
echo "${SYSTEM_USERNAME}    ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/php-fpm${PHP_VERSION}" >> /etc/sudoers.d/${SYSTEM_USERNAME}
...
USER ${SYSTEM_USERNAME}
CMD ["/usr/bin/env", "sh", "-c", "sudo php-fpm${PHP_VERSION} --nodaemonize"]
...
```

It works via docker:

```
$ docker run -dit php7.4-fpm
$ docker exec -it 2e9331162630 ps aux                                                                                                           
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
php-7-4      1  0.0  0.0   2384   764 pts/0    Ss+  15:48   0:00 sh -c sudo php-
root         6  0.0  0.0   6592  3224 pts/0    S+   15:48   0:00 sudo php-fpm7.4
root         7  0.0  0.3 635904 33796 ?        Ss   15:48   0:00 php-fpm: master
www-data     8  0.0  0.0 635904  7968 ?        S    15:48   0:00 php-fpm: pool w
```

And not working via docker-compose:

```
$ docker-compose up
php_1    | 
php_1    | We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
php_1    | Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:
php_1    | 
php_1    |     #1) Respect the privacy of others.
php_1    |     #2) Think before you type.
php_1    |     #3) With great power comes great responsibility.
php_1    | 
php_1    | sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
docker_php_1 exited with code 1
```

**How to avoid sudo password prompt in docker-compose ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if explanation is correct, but it works:

Environment variable `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` is guilty, need to share it

PHP Dockerfile:

```
ENV ...
    # Avoid 'debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog'
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
...
USER root
echo "${SYSTEM_USERNAME}    ALL=NOPASSWD:SETENV: /usr/sbin/php-fpm${PHP_VERSION}" >> /etc/sudoers.d/${SYSTEM_USERNAME}
...
USER ${SYSTEM_USERNAME}
CMD ["/usr/bin/env", "sh", "-c", "sudo --preserve-env=DEBIAN_FRONTEND php-fpm${PHP_VERSION} --nodaemonize"]
```

Thanks to https://superuser.com/a/1001684/192832

Answer (score 1):

Generally you don't use `sudo` in Docker at all: it's all but impossible to safely set a user password, and whenever you run a container, you can directly specify the user ID it uses (with the `docker run -u` option).  Containers only run one process and usually don't have multiple users.

In the particular example you have here, you're in theory running the container as a non-root user, but the main container process is a `sudo` invocation that immediately switches back to the root user.  You can eliminate the intermediate step here and just specify

```
USER root
CMD php-fpm${PHP_VERSION} --nodaemonize
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you allocate pseudo tty with `-t`.
Do same in docker-compose with `tty: true`.

Comment: It's just a habit. `$ docker run -d php7.4-fpm` and `$ docker exec 8fdaaf155629 ps aux` - works as expected

Comment: @cetver did you try `tty: true`?